# Jetty configuration is ignored by spring boot 2.5.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gradle, embedded-jetty

I have the following configuration, but when the application starts it uses tomcat even though I am excluding it and using Jetty

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = '16'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.keycloak.bom:keycloak-adapter-bom:13.0.0"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
    implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter'
}
```

Here is the dependencies tree:

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web -> 2.5.0
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.5.0
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.5.0
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.7
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.7
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.7
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.7
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.7
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.5.0
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.5.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.5.0
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.14.1
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.14.1
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.30
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.28
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.5.0
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.5.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.7
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.3
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.12.3
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.3 (c)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.3 (c)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3 (c)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:2.12.3 (c)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.12.3 (c)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.12.3 (c)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.12.3 (c)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.12.3 (c)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.12.3 (c)
|    |    |    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.12.3 (c)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.3
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.12.3
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.12.3
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.12.3
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.3 (*)
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3 (*)
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.12.3 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.5.0
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.46
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.46
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.46
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.46
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.7 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.7
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.7 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.7 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.7 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.7 (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.7 (*)
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty -> 2.5.0
|    +--- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:4.0.4
|    +--- jakarta.websocket:jakarta.websocket-api:1.1.2
|    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.46
|    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    |         \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |         +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |         |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |         |         +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|    |         |         \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|    |         \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |              \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.41.v20210516
|    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:9.4.41.v20210516
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|    \--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:9.4.41.v20210516
|         +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:9.4.41.v20210516
|         |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:9.4.41.v20210516
|         |    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|         |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|         |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.0
|         |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:9.0
|         |         +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.0
|         |         +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:9.0
|         |         |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.0
|         |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:9.0
|         |              \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:9.0 (*)
|         +--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:9.4.41.v20210516
|         |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
|         \--- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:9.4.41.v20210516 (*)
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -> 2.5.0
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:2.5.0
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.5.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.6
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.5.0
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.5.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:4.0.3
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.3.7
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.7 (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7 (*)
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.7
|    |              +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.7 (*)
|    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7 (*)
|    +--- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:1.3.3
|    +--- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:2.2.3
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.31.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.4.1.Final
|    |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.27.0-GA
|    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.10.21 -> 1.10.22
|    |    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    |    +--- org.jboss:jandex:2.2.3.Final
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.5.1
|    |    +--- org.dom4j:dom4j:2.1.3
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.1.2.Final
|    |    |    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final -> 3.4.1.Final
|    |    \--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1 -> 2.3.4
|    |         +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3
|    |         +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.4
|    |         \--- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:3.0.12
|    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.5.1
|    |    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.5.1
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26 -> 1.7.30
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-orm:5.3.7
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.7 (*)
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26 -> 1.7.30
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.3.7
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.6
+--- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter -> 13.0.0
|    +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-2-adapter:13.0.0
|    |    +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core:13.0.0
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.4.1.Final
|    |    |    \--- org.keycloak:keycloak-core:13.0.0
|    |    |         +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-common:13.0.0
|    |    |         |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68
|    |    |         |    \--- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.2
|    |    |         +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68
|    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.1 -> 2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.1 -> 2.12.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.4.1.Final
|    |    +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-core:13.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-security-adapter:13.0.0
|    |    |    +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-core:13.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-spi:13.0.0
|    |    |    +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-adapter-core:13.0.0
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.4.1.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13 -> 4.4.14
|    |    |    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11 -> 1.15
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.1 -> 2.12.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.5.RELEASE -> 2.5.0 (*)
|    +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-authz-client:13.0.0
|    |    +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-core:13.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.4.1.Final
|    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.3.RELEASE -> 2.5.0 (*)
|    +--- org.keycloak:spring-boot-container-bundle:13.0.0
|    \--- org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-security-adapter:13.0.0 (*)
+--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core -> 4.3.5
|    \--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0 -> 2.3.1
|         \--- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0
+--- org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:13.0.0
|    +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-core:13.0.0 (*)
|    +--- org.keycloak:keycloak-common:13.0.0 (*)
|    +--- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.13.2.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec:2.0.1.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.13.2.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec:2.0.1.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind:jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec:2.0.0.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.3
|    |    |    +--- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:2.0.2
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec:2.0.1.Final
|    |    |    +--- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1 -> 1.2.2
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12 -> 4.5.13 (*)
|    |    |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.5
|    |    |    +--- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0-1
|    |    |    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final -> 3.4.1.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final -> 3.4.1.Final
|    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12 -> 4.5.13 (*)
|    |    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.13 -> 1.15
|    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.5
|    +--- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-multipart-provider:3.13.2.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.13.2.Final (*)
|    |    +--- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.13.2.Final (*)
|    |    +--- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:3.13.2.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind:jboss-jaxb-api_2.3_spec:2.0.0.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.3-b02 -> 2.3.4 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final -> 3.4.1.Final
|    |    +--- com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:1.6.5 -> 1.6.7
|    |    |    \--- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1 -> 1.2.2
|    |    +--- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j:0.6
|    |    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final -> 3.4.1.Final
|    +--- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:3.13.2.Final
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.5 -> 2.12.3 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.5 -> 2.12.3 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.5 -> 2.12.3 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.10.5 -> 2.12.3
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.12.3
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.12.3
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1 -> 1.2.2
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.12.3 (*)
|    |    +--- com.github.fge:json-patch:1.9
|    |    |    \--- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:1.6
|    |    |         +--- com.github.fge:msg-simple:1.1
|    |    |         |    \--- com.github.fge:btf:1.2
|    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.3 -> 2.12.3 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1 -> 28.1-jre
|    |    |              +--- com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1
|    |    |              +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
|    |    |              \--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.8.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre (*)
|    |    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final -> 3.4.1.Final
|    \--- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:3.13.2.Final (*)
\---
```

As well we have tried declaring the exclude on the implementation, but still the same. We started to faced this issue since we moved from spring boot 2.4.3 to 2.5.0

Comment: Have you tried declaring the exclude on the `implementation` configuration rather than on `compile`?

Comment: Yes I have tried this:

implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }

But still the same. We started to faced this issue since we moved from spring boot 2.4.3 to 2.5.0

Comment: It might be coming through one of the other dependencies, Can you run `gradle dependencies` and share the result?

Comment: Hi Nigel, I have attached the gradle dependencies tree